# Default text font format style in android

Tags: android

I am an Android Developer. TextView and EditText are allowed to display text in activity. What is the default text font format style in android? like TimesNewRoman...

From this style: ?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Roboto `normal`. Try out xml   `android:textStyle=""`.

There are 3 default values: bold, italic, normal.

Comment: No, I am not iOS developer, but I think they got `Helvetica`, `Helvetica Neue` as default.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a clear idea on the default style of widgets from the below link

https://raw.github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml

If you search for a textview you would probably end up seeing this

```
<style name="Widget.TextView">    
     <item name="android:textAppearance">android:attr/textAppearanceSmall</item>    
</style>
```

The "textAppearanceSmall" is a theme which is defined in the same file

```
<style name="TextAppearance.Small">    
   <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>    
   <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>    
   <item name="android:textColor">?textColorSecondary</item>    
</style>
```

Hope this helps.